# Can I publish some of Stack Overflow's content on my personal blog?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, licensing

I have a blog on posterous that I use as a bloc-notes-with-bookmarks, everythings I find usefull I put on it as an article.

I didn't find this answer in the FAQ or in the privacy policy, so here I am: in policy terms, can I copy and paste a Stack Overflow question, with the answers I consider useful, and put it in my blog? Citing the source, of course.

Comment: userinvoice is to purpose new functionality/improvement to stackoverflow, not for ask stuff about it ;)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Answer (score 12):

Yes. SO content is licensed CC-BY-SA.

http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/

Comment: Provided that the blog post (or possibly the entire blog?) is also CC-By-SA. SA means that any derived work must be released under the same license.

Comment: Expect if you are the author of the question, in which case you can dual licence your own work