# Can I use questions from Stack Overflow on my site?

Tags: discussion, copyright, creative-commons, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i publish some stackoverflow’s content on my personal blog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/can-i-publish-some-stackoverflows-content-on-my-personal-blog)

I want to make my own Q&A site, but somewhat more specific. I want to know will if there will be any intellectual property rights issues if I include some subset of questions on my site.

I can add a trackback to Stack Overflow if required.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/can-i-publish-some-stackoverflows-content-on-my-personal-blog

Comment: Interesting use: http://askjonskeet.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use SO data on your site, if you follow the rules ([as outlined here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)).

Quote:

> **You are free**
>
> - to Share — to copy, distribute, and transmit the work
> - to Remix — to adapt the work
>
> **Under the following conditions**
>
> - Attribution — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by
>   the author or licensor (but not in any
>   way that suggests that they endorse
>   you or your use of the work).
> - Share Alike — If you alter, transform, or build upon this work,
>   you may distribute the resulting work
>   only under the same or similar license
>   to this one.