# Multiple copies of a SO question closed as "belongs on meta" generated in meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431404/can-i-use-questions-asked-over-stackoverflow-in-my-site) currently has 19 close votes.

More than a dozen duplicate questions of this one have been generated in meta, possibly because of a bug in the migration. See: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42000/can-i-use-questions-asked-over-stackoverflow-in-my-site), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42001/can-i-use-questions-asked-over-stackoverflow-in-my-site), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42002/can-i-use-questions-asked-over-stackoverflow-in-my-site), ..., [N](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42016/can-i-use-questions-asked-over-stackoverflow-in-my-site), ...

[image: shot of the many dupes]

Comment: I flagged the first question for moderator attention - I did think about flagging the others but when I saw how many of them there were I decided against it...

Comment: It's beautiful really.

Comment: Bam, all gone now. A shame really ;-)

Comment: @fretje - all but one, which isn't the first (post 42004 as opposed to post 42000)

Comment: @ChrisF: Wow, that would have been a thousand times the answer to life, the universe and everything!

Comment: +1 for the pink stogey-chomping bunny.

Comment: @Software Monkey: That should be credited to @random :)

Comment: I don't care who gets credit, I love me some cigars and will pretty much always upvote a stogie on Meta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in some refactorings around how our LINQ DataContexts are accessed.

This has been fixed.

Comment: Have you fixed the test that didn't detect this bug? :)

Comment: Ja, natürlich :)

Comment: Und ich dachte immer, Amtssprache der Trilogie wäre ausschließlich Englisch.

Comment: @bal: Zur Not kann ich mich auch mit Deutsch anfreunden. Man ist ja flexibel :)

Answer (score 2):

Also - the [only remaining version on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42004/can-i-use-questions-asked-over-stackoverflow-in-my-site) says it has 2 answers (in both the question-list view and the question page itself), but I can see none on the question page itself:

[borked http://i41.tinypic.com/35jayoj.jpg](http://i41.tinypic.com/35jayoj.jpg)

Comment: I don't think any of the questions had the answers transferred - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42000 (for those with enough rep to see deleted posts)

Comment: It says "3 answers" now, while there's only one visible.

Comment: The image has been removed. Can you please re-post if possible?