# Cannot post any comments; always getting "15 second" message

Tags: bug, status-completed

Clearly, I am not submitting comments every 15 seconds.

I've tried it over the course of 10 minutes, on different threads.

My account on SO is: https://stackoverflow.com/users/154152/silky

One thread I'm trying to post a comment on is: [how to test asynchronous methods using nunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431541/how-to-test-asynchronous-methods-using-nunit)

Comment: +1 It's not just you.

Comment: Strangely enough, this happened to me with the question I link to in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42017/multiple-copies-of-a-so-question-closed-as-belongs-on-meta-generated-in-meta, i.e., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431404/can-i-use-questions-asked-over-stackoverflow-in-my-site; however then I tried to put a comment in _another_ question, picked randomly, and I succeeded. Do you observe the same thing, i.e. cannot post comments to only _some_ questions/answers?

Comment: Hmm, I was just able to post my comment to that thread. I wonder if it was fixed or if I was just lucky ...

Comment: +1 This happened to me for a while, but I have since managed to post a comment.

Comment: Update: I seem to be able to comment now where I previously couldn't.

Comment: The problem is not consistent for me either, sometimes it randomly works. FWIW, SO says "svn revision: 6485" at the moment.

Comment: @Greg - MSO and SO are up to 6487 now.

Comment: @Dominic: yes, new code was deployed since I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deployment artifact -- there were a few places we weren't correctly calling the shared function to get the user IP, and thus the `x-forwarded-for` HTTP header was not respected. Should be fixed in a minute or two.