# Extra votes to migrate lead to multiple posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, migration

[This (now deleted) SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915563/stackoverflow-reputation-repercussions-closed) somehow ended up with 14 people voting to close and migrate it. For each extra vote, an extra copy of the question appeared to have been created on Meta (though they have now been cleaned up).

Now a similar problem has occurred on [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/why-has-this-question-been-migrated-so-many-times-into-meta-closed) where close votes are still somehow being cast.

This was [supposedly fixed months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration/20103#20103), but it's clearly still a problem. [I blame Jarrod](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPKITRUPoRY) and his `goto` statement. =P

**Screenshots:**

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/1160/migrations2.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/1160/migrations2.png)

[alt text http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8155/multiple1.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8155/multiple1.png)

**Update** This is now happening again: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946573/what-is-wrong-with-rep) and [one of the migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51877/what-is-wrong-with-rep)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration However, unlike the previous incidents, I've noticed that people are still voting to migrate that question.

Comment: The question is: should we waste our close votes to clean up the mess?

Comment: @ccomet: Yes, it's up to 14 votes now.

Comment: @Jon I flagged the original post for moderator attention and listed the first 4 duplicate IDs.

Comment: @gnovices-exchange Checking the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2915563/revisions), this has been occurring over the span of 12 minutes, so this doesn't sound like a "race condition" error anymore.

Comment: How the heck did Joel vote *twice* on this ? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/why-has-this-question-been-migrated-so-many-times-into-meta-closed

Comment: @Essjaaay: The virus has mutated and spread to Meta!

Comment: Maybe it's just a really, *really* important question. I mean, "repercussions" - that sounds ominous.

Comment: @gnov & @aaro LOL!

Comment: "... it can only be Jarrod!" Edit: 10 random upvotes to anyone who can find and link to an actual Commercial for Jared's with that stupid jingle.

Comment: @Randolpho: Check the new edit. ;)

Comment: What is Jared's?

Comment: @mmyers: It's a chain of jewelry stores: http://www.jared.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/home|10451|10001|-1|

Comment: @gnovices-exchange: I found that one... *not* a real commercial, but gets the general gist well enough. I'll give you.... 3 random upvotes.

Comment: FIRST!  ;-)  (I swear it wasn't my fault!)

Comment: It's happened again; still too localized?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51577/is-stackoverflow-having-problems-or-is-my-browser-not-understanding-javascript-an

Comment: I blame Jarrod...

Comment: Duplicate "Closed as duplicate": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946513/in-c-as-free-knows-an-array-size-why-isnt-there-a-function-that-gets-the-arr

Comment: @sth:  Maybe it is my fault, then :-P  I voted to close that one too.  Maybe I'll stop voting to close things and we'll see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Also related (or duplicate) of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42017/multiple-copies-of-a-so-question-closed-as-belongs-on-meta-generated-in-meta

Answer (score 2):

CPU spiked to 100% across all 4 CPUs on one web server (we're still looking at why) and caused some odd side effects. This being one of them.

Closing as "too localized"

Comment: I've seen it happen a couple more times in the last day. Maybe it's not so localized, unless the servers are routinely getting hammered on.

Comment: @gnovices yes, it is possible to have race conditions on migration -- that's a known issue.

Comment: I know about the race conditions, but that doesn't appear to be what happened on, for example, this question that was closed as NARQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935364/i-am-a-newer-for-stackoverflow-closed. The repeated closings are spread across 5 minutes.

Comment: Jeff, this is happening again. See the update that I put into the question. I think that this happening multiple times is common enough to not be closed as "too localized"

Comment: I blame Jarrod...

Comment: These side-effects should be caught and cleaned up after, automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This is hopefully fixed - we had to make some changes in how we were locking questions during close voting.

We'll be monitoring migrations closely :)