# Super bug! Multiple migrations

Tags: bug, migration

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why has this question been migrated so many times into Meta ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/why-has-this-question-been-migrated-so-many-times-into-meta)
>   [Extra votes to migrate lead to multiple posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/extra-votes-to-migrate-lead-to-multiple-posts)

Look at the meta homepage right now. You'll see a ton of duplicate questions. Now here's the weird thing. These duplicate questions were migrated from a single SO question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915563/stackoverflow-reputation-repercussions-closed is the SO link

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/stackoverflow-reputation-repercussions is one of the Meta links

Example screenshots: 
[alt text http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8155/multiple1.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8155/multiple1.png)

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/1160/migrations2.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/1160/migrations2.png)

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/why-has-this-question-migrated-so-many-times-into-meta

Comment: @Pop was that one created before mine? Both were in the same minute

Comment: This is the earliest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/extra-votes-to-migrate-lead-to-multiple-posts

Comment: @Earlz: Your question 18:24:16, the other question 18:24:02.  Well within honest dupe limits.  But I thought they should be merged.  Seems like this is being sorted out by the community now, though.

Comment: @Pop Demand - Well the earliest question wasn't around when I posted mine. Voted to close mine anyway. Talk about making mess of a mess!

Comment: Now we have to start posting questions about all the questions that were posted about the duplicate questions.

Comment: @Earlz @Essjaaay @gnovices All I wanted to do was head off a branched discussion on the topic, not start a timestamp argument.  But now it's just creating additional cruft.  This is my last statement on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought the original user just posted his question that many times and it was migrated that many times, but the revisions list clearly shows it's the same post.