# Slow response times from stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Anyone currently experiencing a slow response time from stackoverflow.com?  I received no response or 504 bad gateway error.

Comment: The intertubz are clogged.

Comment: I got 502 Bad Gateway once. The `ping` time is significantly longer than meta (by a factor of 2 to 10.)

Comment: @Robert: You weren't supposed to delete the first comment. :)

Comment: How do I accept an answer to this question?  Until one of the employees verifies the event that caused the slow response time.

Comment: I'm having trouble with SF right now. The question page loads pretty quickly (or appears to) but it IE8 still says "Waiting for http://serverfault.com/..." in the status bar and some of the controls (mark as answer) won't work

Answer (score 3):

I saw this a moment ago as well, but I think the actual slow part is the sstatic.com domain they use for static content.  I think this *usually* means they just updated a file or two there and it's slow for a few minutes while everyone has to update their browser cache with the new version of whatever they changed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be back to normal now, but while it happened I was awarded a badge. Maybe the badge-awarding batch process is to blame.

Comment: Maybe **you're** to blame!  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Hey, where's *my* badge?

Comment: @Bill: When I give a Nice Answer, Stack Overflow immediately stops all activity until it has awarded me with my rightly deserved badge. 
Sounds appropriate to me.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about the medal ceremony. Congratulations.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It was that way a few minutes ago during this catastrophe [Extra votes to migrate lead to multiple posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/extra-votes-to-migrate-lead-to-multiple-posts) but now that the question is deleted it seems to be going at normal speeds

Comment: Perhaps the update that Joel implies is what actually caused that catastrophe. If not the update, then the act of updating itself, perhaps.

Comment: I actually think it's more likely the "catastrophe" caused one of the devs to rush out a fix and cause the update.