# Post closed three times as duplicate?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I don't know if this is related to the [multiple-migrate problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/extra-votes-to-migrate-lead-to-multiple-posts) or the [slow response problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51319/slow-response-times-from-stackoverflow-com) but looking at the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51309/revisions) of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/why-has-this-question-been-migrated-so-many-times-into-meta) - makes me wonder - what the heck happened?

Comment: Some questions are closed with extreme prejudice.

Comment: I think there's been a problem with closing/migrating on all the sites.

Comment: Makes me wonder if this is at all similar to what happened back on May 8th with the migration votes.

Comment: @ccomet Any Meta links for the same ?

Comment: -cough- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51281/is-it-necessary-to-delete-time-local-closed-bug-reports-on-meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a massive CPU spike on one of the web servers (4 cpus, all pegged) which caused some strange behavior.

Closing as too localized.