# How did I manage to vote twice to close, on two separate cycles of closing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

If you look at the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2682561/revisions) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682561/learning-python-in-one-weekend) (pointed out to me by [The Cat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/54262/the-cat)), you can see I voted to close once, then there's a bunch of deleting and undeleting, and then I somehow voted to close again after it was reopened.

There have been a number of bugs lately with [migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/extra-votes-to-migrate-lead-to-multiple-posts)/[close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51325/post-closed-three-times-as-duplicate) votes, and for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51309/why-has-this-question-been-migrated-so-many-times-into-meta-closed) Joel was able to vote twice in the same closing cycle.

I'm not sure if my being able to vote more than once on separate closing cycles is related to the other bugs happening recently, or if the one-close-vote limit somehow gets reset when questions undergo deletion/undeletion. Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I guess it doesn't have anything to do with deletion/undeletion, since I was able to vote to close [this question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913701/am-i-a-dinosaur-programmer) even though I had [voted to close it (successfully) about 3 days (maybe just barely 4 days) ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2913701/revisions).

Comment: Re career questions: I recently saw Neil Butterworth say "You manage your career by making your own decisions, not by asking some random bunch of guys on the internet what they think you should do," which is the shortest and most succinct I've seen it put in a while.  But I think I'll hold off on voting again myself on that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The behavior has changed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99141/bogus-you-have-already-voted-to-close-this-question-on-expired-votes) Now, close votes still expire (but the expiration only starts once a question has reached 100 views), but the fact that you have cast a close vote does not expire, so if you have an expired closed vote on a question, you will not be able to vote again to close this question (whether the question has been closed and reopened in the meantime or not).