# Expired reopen votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please re-allow expired close votes to be re-cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99333/please-re-allow-expired-close-votes-to-be-re-cast)

Over there on travel SE we have a [very controversial question about sex in a plane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3677/cheapest-way-that-doesnt-lend-me-in-legal-trouble-to-join-the-mile-high-club). It was closed by Joel which was also discussed controversially. Some people voted to reopen but since we're still in beta, not enough reopen votes could be acquired. Now there was a edit to make the question more suitable and some people want to reopen it again. But the problem is, the reopen votes are expired and although it is a long time ago, you can't vote a second time to reopen.

Is there any possibility to get back an expired reopen vote? E.g. after a major edit? Especially on small sites this would be important

Comment: ... must resist to open that link at work :)

Comment: It is safe for work ;)