# How many times you can vote to re-open a question during its lifetime?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

It appears that I can only vote to re-open a question once during its lifetime. Is this true?

I noticed this because I voted to re-open a question. Nothing happened and the vote expired, however a few weeks later I noticed another user voting to re-open the same question. I tried adding my vote, however it told me I had already voted to re-open the question so wouldn't let me add my vote.

Is it true that I only get one re-open vote per question?

Comment: That's right: *• You can only vote to close once per question; • You can only vote to reopen once per question*

Comment: @JeremyBanks Thanks, I didn't think to check the "closed question FAQ" to find out the number of re-open votes allowed. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Also, do you know if editing the question resets the re-open vote count, or resets the number of times you're allowed to vote to re-open?

Comment: see also [Please re-allow expired close votes to be re-cast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99333/please-re-allow-expired-close-votes-to-be-re-cast)

Comment: @Rachel Editing resets nothing. Reopen permissions and mechanics are also 100% linked and matched with close permissions and mechanics - as such, for your future research, always check how it works with closures. You'll find the answer for reopening to be generally identical. ♪

Comment: @Rachel It doesn't, they're never reset. You'd probably need to flag a mod at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've guessed correctly. From [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question):

> ### What are the limits for 3,000+ rep users?
>
> - *[...]*
> - You can only vote to close once per question
> - You can only vote to reopen once per question

**Edit**

You cannot vote to re-open a question a 2nd time after it has been edited.