# Is there a way to recover how people voted to close a question post-close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, data-explorer

When the question has close votes (<5), and you click on "Close" link, in the dialog for closing it shows you how many people voted for each of separate options (e.g. 1 voted as Duplicate, 3 voted as Opinion based).

However, that is no longer possible to find out after the 5th vote is cast; and the question is closed - the final result only displays the "final" voting reason which I presume was the majority of the vote types.

Once the question was closed, is it possible to recover what specific closing reasons were cast on it? (from GUI or from **Data Explorer**).

I tried `PostFeedback` and `Votes` tables, and neither seemed to contain close vote records, the latter only listed downvotes.

Comment: Side note - the voters clearly ARE someplace in the system since the closed questions always shows WHO closed.

Comment: I THINK that this may be because of [close vote expiration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124716/119280) but not certain. The question I tried was closed 1/18/2014

Comment: Not with the data-explorer, I think. The post history only contains the voters, not what they voted for.

Comment: related: [After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773)