# After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, close-reasons, timeline, attribution

Suggest to expose close votes distinguished by reason in question timeline page after question is closed.

Purpose of this feature is to help in discussing cases of closure when knowing vote split would be useful to avoid unnecessary tension. *"Oh no I would never ever close this as unclear! I swear I picked some other reason, [it is not my fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180550/165773)!"*

Related:

- [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason?noredirect=1#comment923868_54917) (score over +300 and 13 bounties from 8 users in 11 years)

> Exposing close votes in the timeline is probably the easiest of all options here: doesn't require backfilling data for close records, doesn't require adding stuff to the data-dump... If folks are happy to see their close votes exposed on an obscure page, that's actually feasible. Post a specific feature-request, please.

- Explanation of why more explicit exposure was [considered undesirable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239536/165773):

> The reason we display a big banner with large text when a question is closed is to show the author and any passers-by that the questions isn't a good fit for the site. In the case of the author, we want them to know what they can fix. Throwing several reasons at them at once, especially if they're just top-level reasons without full explanations, isn't very helpful. How do you choose where to start if you see four lines of giant text screaming at you? You probably don't; you probably just walk away.

The close reason that receives the majority of votes is usually a good indicator of what the *primary* problem is...

Comment: Related: [When you hover over the name of the person closing a question it should show the reason they've chosen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2519/310998)

Comment: I think this feature request should be revisited and implemented, especially since we have users abusing the “too broad” close reason to close questions that lack research effort.

Comment: Agree. Else [3 users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401919/detailed-closed-reasons?noredirect=1#comment801166_401919) (one assumes that they are different people) with more than 3k that have a different opinion/interpretation, can close one's question. The way it is now doesn't play in favor of those that want to contribute to the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), we don't have immediate plans to work on this request. However, we are planning to start some discovery work in late 2021 on the question close experience and will revisit this request when we start on that project.

Answer (score 11):

This remains fairly trivial compared to the other requests for breaking out close reasons, as the information is already displayed in the timeline for moderators.

In light of that, I would recommend one small tweak to the proposal:

**Display all *non-pending* close and reopen votes in the timeline.**

...where non-pending just means they've either already taken effect, *or will never take effect.* E.g., the question has been closed or reopened, the vote has aged away or been retracted.

This avoids potentially misleading situations where a post is closed with *some* aged or retracted votes which nevertheless had an influence on closure (kicking off review, prompting edits, etc). Also has a nice symmetry with the rule for displaying review tasks.