# "You have already voted to close" -- question was reopened

Tags: support, vote-to-close

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7475221/561731 was closed due it not being a real question.

Now it was reopened and it is a duplicate. So, as usual, I click on close but I get this dialog:

[image: screenshot]

Hmmmmm… This is odd; I voted to have it closed **before**, but that was something completely different.

Should I not be able to vote to close for completely different reasons (or even for the same reason if the opinion stands?) since the question has now been reopened?

---

This has been discussed previously on [Please allow expired close/open votes to be re-cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99333/please-re-allow-expired-close-votes-to-be-re-cast) and [Bogus "You have already voted to close this question" on expired votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99141/bogus-you-have-already-voted-to-close-this-question-on-expired-votes).

Comment: Sort of similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99141/bogus-you-have-already-voted-to-close-this-question-on-expired-votes/99234#99234

Comment: @eldarerathis I have added it to the OP

Comment: Why was that reopened...oy. Voting to close when my votes come back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This restriction exists because when it *didn't* exist folks would get into "close-wars", wherein the same sets of users would repeatedly re-open and re-close controversial questions. Yes, it *does* break use-cases where questions must be closed repeatedly. Fortunately, those are less common.

When you find a question that you've already voted on in need of some closin', flag for a moderator. Resolving these situations is their bread-and-butter<sup>*</sup>.

Note that the expired vote scenario you link to is a *little* bit different (and a much more recent change to the closing system). Though again, the idea is that if you can't get a resolution by normal voting, the solution is to escalate it to the moderators, not keep voting impotently in hope that something will change.

<sup>*<sub>Ok, so mods don't get paid, so this is strictly non-nutritional fake imitation bread and non-dairy butter.</sub></sup>

Comment: hah. Exactly what I thought, as of my comment "Can you imagine that war between close voters and reopen voters?"