# Is Stack Overflow having problems or is my browser not understanding JavaScript anymore?

Tags: support, javascript

Something funny is happening. Besides "Ask question", nothing else works for me. I tried to edit one of my posts, upvote/downvote posts, add comments. Nothing worked.
Javascript is enabled in the browser, and I don't have any Firefox addon that would interfere with the content of the page.
Is this happening to you too, or am I the only one?

Comment: >8k rep, you should know better where to post this.

Comment: you should know where to post this, after enough rep.

Comment: I wanted to see if other people could post comments from the main website.

Comment: Multi-migration, flagged for moderator cleanup again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your cache.Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to deactivate the WebGuard of my AntiVir-application.

Something in the JavaScript-code of this (and relating) sites does obviously look suspicious to some anti-virus-applications.