# Closed with more than five votes?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close

I've seen this happen a few times recently: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2923424/revisions

That question has **ten** close votes, with each vote after four causing a new "Post Closed" entry. I always assumed it was a race condition, where a couple people all close simultaneously, but this one shows new votes 15 minutes after the original five closed the question. How does that happen?

Comment: Possible dupes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/extra-votes-to-migrate-lead-to-multiple-posts-closed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration

Comment: @Ran I saw the first, but Jeff seemed to indicate it was a temporary problem, unless it happened again to cause this. The second was caused by a bug fixed a year ago, so it can't be this

Comment: On the other hand, the first problem [just happened again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51494/which-genius-downgraded-my-question-please-give-more-detail-after-downgrade), so it clearly isn't fixed. That might be the cause of this as well

Comment: I also saw this some time ago http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42017/multiple-copies-of-a-so-question-closed-as-belongs-on-meta-generated-in-meta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is hopefully fixed - we had to make some changes in how we were locking questions during close voting.

Comment: Seems it might not have been fixed in 2011: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411348/ampps-as-a-production-server