# Question had enough close votes to be closed, but was not closed

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65695015/208273) on Stack Overflow required 4 votes to close, despite the requirement on Stack Overflow being only 3 votes to close a question.  [A similar bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51909/165261) was fixed and marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in 2010 (though the comments note its reappearance).

I suspect this was caused by a server error partway through the request for the final close vote.  When I cast the third close vote, I received an error (unfortunately, I didn't take note of it at the time).  It doesn't appear to be an issue of the last two close votes coming in simultaneously: some time elapsed between the third and fourth votes, allowing me to click around and refresh a few times before the last vote was cast.

Here is what the question looked like after I cast the third close vote and refreshed the page:

[image: screenshot of an open Stack Overflow question with 3 close votes]

And here is what it looked like after someone else cast the fourth, closing it:

[image: screenshot of a closed Stack Overflow question with 4 close votes]

Comment: This is, I think, the same trick Shog once used to close a question as a duplicate of multiple targets, before the feature to edit the target list was implemented. He'd cast a binding vote for one target, then trigger a server error while that was being processed, then vote for the other.

Comment: There [exists the possibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353918/282094) that one vote was retracted, another cast, then it closed on three valid votes without the deletion of the retracted one firing in time.